# How do I do "nested if" in JSTL for Java JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to do something like the following:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:when test="${empty example2}">
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
        </c:otherwise>              
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Is this even possible?  I get an exception thrown when trying to run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to do it more like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}"> 
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </c:when> 
    <c:otherwise> 
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty example2}"> 
                <!-- do different stuff -->
            </c:when> 
            <c:otherwise> 
                <!-- do default stuff -->
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

The verbosity shown here is a good example of why XML is a poor language for implementing multi-level conditional statements.

Comment: Maybe so, but this level of verbosity isn't necessary.  @BalusC has a more elegant and readable solution below.  It means the same thing, because `c:when` followed by `c:otherwise` is the same as `if-else if`.

Comment: Fair enough, but even the alternate example is clunky and verbose.  The `c:choose` adds nothing whatsoever of value in terms of human readability, for instance, nor does having to specify the logical condition as `test=`, and so on.  My example can be simplified, but XML is still a very poor language for representing if/elseif/else logic.

Answer (score 11):

You can use multiple `<c:when>`s in a `<c:choose>`.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty example1}">
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${empty example2}">
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    </c:otherwise>              
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree that this is always possible.  The scenario I have displays a message in a form when users do not have a certain permissions.  <c:otherwise> then shows a set of radio buttons if they do have those permissions.  Nested inside that is another conditional radio button offered to a further subset of users.  Thanks for a good discussion!

Comment: Hate to hijack, but can you please take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622126/if-else-or-when-condition-in-jstl. Thank you so much, and sorry again OP! Had to get someone's attention :)

Comment: This is not usually what is meant by 'nested'.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @BalusC--you can simplify the statement.  Remember that `c:when` statements are mutually exclusive, like `if-else if` blocks.

The [JSTL 1.2 spec](http://java.coe.psu.ac.th/J2EE/JSTL1.2/jstl-1_2-mrel2-spec.pdf) states that `c:choose` must be the parent of at least one `c:when` statement, and that `c:when` must always precede at least one `c:otherwise` statement with the same immediate parent. Essentially, that also means that every `c:when` must have a `c:otherwise` following it inside a `c:choose`, and a `c:choose` must surround any `c:when` + `c:otherwise`. From what I can see, the spec does not refer to nesting `c:choose` elements, so I don't know whether it works--but I don't think you will ever be forced into nesting them.